# SharePoint 2010 print labels for barcodes attached to list items

Tags: 2010, printing, barcodes

I have a SharePoint list which I have enabled barcodes. The process works great - a user adds a list item and the barcode gets automatically generated for it. What I need to do is let a user select a set of the list items, the print the barcodes for them on standard Avery (or generic) 2x4 labels. This seems like such a reasonable thing to want to do with barcodes, however I have not found any straight-forward way to accomplish it. I will add that my site is using claims based authentication, and it is not guaranteed that users will have the knowledge to integrate Office products (if they have them) with the site. I would ideally like to generate a pdf with the selected barcodes on the server and deliver it to users in a new window when they click a print button. What options are there?

Answer (score 1):

Formatted printing from a website is notoriously unreliable and dynamic PDF generation is easily capable of crippling your server.  I would recommend developing a Word Macro that pulls in the data from SharePoint and then formats it as barcodes in Word.

There is also [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/recman/archive/2006/08/10/694087.aspx), though I'm not sure how relevant it is to your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account what Dave Wise has said, I have had pretty good luck using Silverlight to print items. You might want to consider using the Client Object Model and Silverlight to accomplish this.